# Is this a valid a way to use split?

Tags: java

I am trying to practice identifying whether or not a code is valid just by looking at it. I can't find anything about split method implementation that looks like this, and I want to know why.

```
String[] names = "flowers,are,pretty".split(",",0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid.

```
String[] names = "flowers,are,pretty".split(",",0);
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    System.out.println(names[i]);
```

For more info visit [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid statement

```
    String[] arr = "flowers,are,pretty".split(",",0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

There is no need of specify limit 0 in the context . Just can use

```
   String[] arr = "flowers,are,pretty".split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` has a `split()` overload that takes an `int` parameter, documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)). Calling it with 0 is [equivalent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to calling the single-parameter overload.